# How do you get a list of files with Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a list of file ids that I want to refresh with up-to-date metadata. I know there is a file/get method that I could call for each file, but it's obviously not the right way to deal with it if we have many files.

So I've looked for the file/list and its "q" parameter to make a search query. Unfortunately, it looks like it doesn't accept the "id IN (?, ?)" format.

So is there a clever way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap all of the file/get/put calls into a single batch.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#batching_resource_operations_into_a_single_request

Comment: Hello Pinoyyid, I'm not using this API and I don't think we can do that with the Google Drive SDK, or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Drive API and the V3 Docs List API aren't that dissimilar so it's OK to mix-n-match in your app.

You're right that batch is only supported in V3 Docs List, not yet in Drive SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all those files to a specific folder and then search for them using the `parents` field of a search query, as in:

```
'1234567' in parents
```

that returns all files that are contained in the folder with ID 1234567.

Comment: Thanks for your help Claudio. That's still 2 requests instead of one and that would be really disturbing for the final user if he starts to get folders created for technical reasons like this, don't you think?

Comment: I agree about the fact that creating folders for technical reasons is probably not the best user experience and actually we are already working on something to address that. Stay tuned, I can't announce anything yet

Comment: Great thanks Claudio. I suppose a straight forward way to do it would be to accept the "id" column in the "q" parameter of files/list

Comment: If you go with Claudio's folder approach, you can make it 'hidden' so the use won't ever see it.

Comment: In fact, I'll go more with the wait & see approach :-)

Comment: To be clear, I was talking about a solution to the technical folder issue, not the way to pass a list of ids to the q parameter. However, we are also considering batching requests which might help with that

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to download the items before you update them?

Given you have the file ID, you can simply PUT your changes.

Comment: Thanks Pinoyyid for your help. Actually, I don't want to PUT changes, just make sure to get up-to-date metadata of these files.The thumbnail link and downloadUrl change all the time and expire after an hour or so. So having a cached metadata isn't of any help if the file wasn't download in the following hour.